# How to run a php file from docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a docker project and I want to run a php file which will configure the database for the project.

My Docker file :

```
FROM php:7.2-apache  
LABEL maintainer="admin@ksoftlabs.com"  
COPY site/ /var/www/html  
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html  
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli  
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-    available/000-default.conf  
EXPOSE 80  
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    db:
      image: mysql
      command: 
        --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: group_db
    server:
        image : apache
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

I want to run the install.php which will be in /var/www/html/ directory. How can I do that?

**Edit : I want to run this file automatically after the container is up**

Comment: I would recommend you to review the following step-by-step page https://alysivji.github.io/php-mysql-docker-containers.html
to configure your PHP website correctly.

Comment: @Yair.Thank you. But how do I run this file automatically without having to visit it via a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Would running it earlier work?

After `RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli`, put `RUN php /path/to/your/file.php`?

Comment: Yes. It cannot be run like that because it is a php file which will create the database in the MySQL database. At the time of building the docker image the database would not be running. Therefore I have to run the php file from the docker-compose.yml